# Why would scanf make my switch statement freak out?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I can't seem to figure out why my program doesn't work if I call `scanf()` from within a `case` statement.

Everything works fine until I call `scanf()`. It's a really small console based menu. It reads a string that has just been entered and goes down the menu accordingly. It all works fine until I try `scanf()` in an integer that it should respond to.

I first thought that returning a value will break the Switch statement... then that didn't work so I placed `break` statements in just in case. But it still doesn't work though. As soon as the `scanf()` is not commented the whole sequence is just messed up.

```
void main(void) {
  char MenuS;
  MenuS = 's';
  while (MenuS != 'q') {
    MenuS = Menu();
  }
}

char Menu() {
  unsigned char Menu;
  unsigned char UserInput[9];
  unsigned int Offset;
  Offset = 0;
  printf("\nEnt:");
  gets(UserInput);
  trim(UserInput);

  if (UserInput[0] != 'q') {
    switch (UserInput[0]) {
    case 'r':
      scanf("%d", &Offset);
      printf("\nIn R");
      return ('r');
      break;
    case 'w':
      // printf("Is w");
      printf("\nIn W");
      return ('w');
      break;
    default:
      printf("\nSomething else");
      break;
    }
  } else {
    return 'q';
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the code supposed to do, and what actually happens? And what is your input?

Comment: My input will be 'r' or 'w'...will add more later on! Then depending on the option it should ask for a number Hench->Scanf(). After that it will call a function with the Integer and return a value.
What I meant with it doesn work is the that when I call ScanF from within the Switch it seems to ignore the Return AND the Break and just to Default which just prints "Not Something"...

Comment: So,your scanf dosen't take any input?

Comment: On which operating system and with which compiler -and which compilation flags- are you developing your program ?

Comment: To prevent UB, change `while(isspace(p[l - 1])) p[--l] = 0;` to `while(*p && isspace(p[l - 1])) p[--l] = 0;`.  `while(* p && isspace(* p)) ++p, --l;` may be simplified to `while(isspace(*p)) ++p, --l;` as `isspace(0)` is false.  Suggest `size_t l = strlen(p);` vs `int l = strlen(p);`.

Comment: 1) Avoid mixing `scanf("%d",...` with `gets()` as the first leaves the `'\n'` in the IO buffer and the second does not.  2) Do no use `gets()`, but `fgets()`.

Comment: What about optimization ?

Comment: "returning a value will break the Switch statement" -- of course it does. You would know what is actually going on if you would print (in hex) UserInput[0] in your default case.

Comment: "What about optimization ? " -- A famous computer scientist said "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Why the heck would you care about optimization when processing user input? Human reactions are at the level of fractions of a second, the computer operates at nanosecond levels.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a problem, because you declared an unsigned int variable, but you used a wrong format specifier here:

```
scanf("%d", &Offset);
```

Offset is an unsigned int variable.

You have to use `%u` for unsigned integer instead of `%d`

Try this, this might solve the problem:

```
scanf("%u", &Offset);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still does the same thing :(

Comment: @BaddaBoompshhh Hmm, maybe it's because you're using both return and break statement at the same time, try removing the break statement.

Comment: @BaddaBoompshhh Oh, and can I ask you, why you have double quotes at the end of your break statement in default ? `break;;`

Comment: The break statments where not there actually. I used them there afterwards in hopes of finding a solution.
Just saw the double :

Answer (score 1):

Learn to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile using `gcc -Wall -g`

Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step.

At last, *read the documentation* of functions that you are using. [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is documented to return an integer number:

> ```
>    These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>    and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>    the event of an early matching failure.
> ```

```
   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
   either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
   EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
   indicate the error.
```

So you should code probably

```
 if (scanf("%d", &Offset)<1) { perror("scanf failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

BTW, your [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) format strings look strange: they should *end* (not start) with a newline `\n` e.g. code `printf("In R\n");` or even better

```
  printf("line %d of %s: In R\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
```

or at least call explicitly `fflush(NULL);` after them, read
about [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and remember that [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_%28computer_science%29).

At last, **[gets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)** is *deprecated* and **dangerous**, use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) or preferably [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). So at least replace `gets(UserInput);` with

```
memset (UserInput, 0, sizeof(UserInput));
if (NULL == fgets(UserInput, sizeof(UserInput), stdin)) 
  { perror("fgets"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

BTW, your `main` function is incorrectly declared. It should be `int main (int argc, char**argv);`  preferably. It should not return `void`  but `EXIT_SUCCESS` i.e. 0 on success and something else on failure. See also `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` and [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)

PS. You are missing several `#include` directives at the beginning of your program, at least:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I assume your code have them but you did not show them to us.

NB: Using capital letters in variables is not conventional in C. Generally, people
reserve upper-case letters for macros. But that is a convention.

Comment: Yes sorry I I didnt add everything.
You explanation is really well put and just taught me allot of things :)! 
Thanks allot!

Comment: How do I use fgets() for User Input though?

Answer (score 0):

> when I call ScanF from within the Switch it seems to ignore the Return AND the Break and just to Default which just prints "Not Something"..

If it "ignored the `return` and the `break`" then you would fall through  to the `case 'w'`. But that isn't happening. Therefore it is not ignoring the return and the break (not that that is possible anyway).

Actually the program flow is working just as you wrote it. The sequence is:

- `scanf("%d", &Offset);`
- You type some numbers **and press enter**
- `return ('r');`
- back to main: `MenuS = Menu();` - `MenuS` is now `'r'`
- `while (MenuS != 'q') { MenuS = Menu();` - call `Menu` again
- `gets(UserInput);`  - gets the blank string you typed earlier
- `if (UserInput[0] != 'q')` - true, since `UserInput[0]` is `0`, the end-of-string marker for your blank string
- `switch (UserInput[0]) {` there is no `case 0`, so `default:` is entered
- `printf("\nSomething else");`

To fix this: you need to discard the Enter that was pressed after you typed in the number. One way is to put this code straight after the `scanf`:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) {}
```

Note, your code has a lot of other problems but this was the main issue.

Comment: Thanks you where right about that.
I know that its impossible for code to just fall through but it really did seem like it on the output.
Of course a valid explanation for all things.
Thanks !